# urbackup installation problem in ubuntu12.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-sources

after `./configure`
I run `make` command but I got this error how to fix it...

```
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "liburbackupserver.so" && ln -s "liburbackupserver.so.0.0.0" "liburbackupserver.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/liburbackupserver.a  dllmain.o stringtools.o os_functions_lin.o server.o server_get.o server_hash.o server_image.o sha2.o data.o FileClient.o tcpstack.o server_prepare_hash.o server_update.o server_status.o server_channel.o server_ping.o server_log.o escape.o server_writer.o bufmgr.o server_running.o server_cleanup.o server_settings.o server_update_stats.o helper.o json.o lastacts.o login.o progress.o salt.o templ.o users.o piegraph.o usage.o usagegraph.o status.o settings.o backups.o logs.o isimageready.o getimage.o google_chart.o download_client.o TreeDiff.o TreeNode.o TreeReader.o ChunkPatcher.o CompressedPipe.o InternetServiceConnector.o InternetServicePipe.o md5.o settingslist.o FileClientChunked.o adler32.o server_archive.o filedownload.o shutdown.o snapshot_helper.o verify_hashes.o cleanup_cmd.o repair_cmd.o ServerCleanupDAO.o mdb.o midl.o MDBFileCache.o DatabaseFileCache.o create_files_cache.o FileCache.o SQLiteFileCache.o livelog.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/liburbackupserver.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "liburbackupserver.la" && ln -s "../liburbackupserver.la" "liburbackupserver.la" )
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/spat/Downloads/urbackup-server-1.3.2/urbackupserver'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/spat/Downloads/urbackup-server-1.3.2/urbackupserver'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/spat/Downloads/urbackup-server-1.3.2'
spat@spat-OEM:~/Downloads/urbackup-server-1.3.2$
```

Answer (score 0):

Urbackup can be installed upto 13.10 from the Launchpad repository [ppa:uroni/urbackup](https://launchpad.net/~uroni/+archive/urbackup).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uroni/urbackup

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install urbackup-server
```